# Vue. Как из дочернего компонента вызвать пропсы родительского

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js

Есть родительский компонент который может принимать `<slot />`, и некоторые пропсы
Как в `<slot />` (детей), использовать методы (или пропсы) родительского компонента? Если это в Vue можно реализовать как-то и является правильным подходом вообще.

Я пишу на реакте, там можно переопределить children:

```
children = React.Children.toArray(children).map(child=> {
  return React.cloneElement(child, {
      active,
      _onChange: (value, label)=> onChange(value, label),
      ...child.props
  });
});
```

Есть ли что-то похожие в Vue, либо я куда-то не туда копаю? Может в Vue вообще данный подход не уместен и есть другой способ использовать какие-то "общие" пропсы?

Answer (score 1):

this.$parent помог решить проблему